# Efficient way to use filter() twice in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am relatively new to Django and Python, but I have not been able to quite figure this one out.

I essentially want to query the database using filter for a large number of users. Then I want to make a bunch of queries on this just this section of users. So I thought it would be most efficient do first query for my larger filter parameters, and then make my separate filter queries on that set. In code, it looks like this

```
#Get the big groups of users, like all people with brown hair.
group_of_users  = Data.objects.filter(......) 

#Now get all the people with brown hair and blue eyes, and then all with green eyes, etc.
for each haircolor :
  subset_of_group = group_of_users.filter(....)
```

That is just pseudo-code by the way, I am not that inept. I thought this would be more efficient, but it seems that if eliminate the first query and simply just get the querysets in the for loop, it is much faster (actually timed).
I fear this is because when I filter first, and then filter each time in the for loop, it is actually doing both sets of filter queries on each for loop execution. So really, doing twice the amount of work I want. I thought with caching this would not matter, as the first filter results would be cached and it would still be faster, but again, I timed it with multiple tests and the single filter is faster. Any ideas?

EDIT:
So it seems that querying for a set of data, and then trying to further query only against that set of data, is not possible. Rather, I should query for a set of data and then further parse that data using regular Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As garnertb ans lanzz said, it doesn't matter where you use the `filter` function, the only thing that matters is when you evaluate the query (see [when querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). My guess is that in your tests, you evaluate the queryset somewhere in your code, and that you do more evaluations in your test with separate filter calls.

Whenever a queryset is evaluated, its results are cached. However, this cache does not carry over if you use another method, such as `filter` or `order_by`, on the queryset. SO you can't try to evaluate the bigger set, and use filtering on the queryset to retrieve the smaller sets without doing another query.

If you only have a small set of haircolours, you can get away with doing a query for each haircolour. However, if you have many of them, the amount of queries will have a severe impact on performance. In that case it might be better to do a query for the full set of users you want to use, and the do subsequent processing in python:

```
qs = Data.objects.filter(hair='brown')
objects = dict()
for obj in qs:
   objects.setdefault(obj.haircolour, []).append(obj)

for (k, v) in objects.items():
    print "Objects for colour '%s':" % k
    for obj in v:
        print "- %s" % obj
```

Comment: OK, so as I feared there is essentially no way to QUERY for a big set of data, and then QUERY only on that smaller set efficiently. Instead, I should look into QUERYING for a set of data, and then just using python to further split up that data. If I am understanding that correctly please just leave a small comment

Comment: Your overcomplicated `try: except KeyError` statement can be simplified as `objects.setdefault(obj.haircolour, []).append(obj)`

Comment: @lanzz Ah, I like that method of building that dict. Updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Filtering Django querysets does not perform *any* database operation, until you actually try to access the result. Filtering only adds conditions to the queryset, which are then used to build the final query when you access the result of the query.

When you assign `group_of_users = Data.objects.filter(...)`, no data is retrieved from the database; you just get a queryset that *knows* that you *want* records that satisfy a specific condition (the filtering parameters you supplied to `Data.objects.filter`), but it does not pre-fetch those actual users. After that, when you assign `subset_of_group = group_of_users.filter(....)`, you don't filter just that previous group of users, but only add more conditions to the queryset; still no data has been retrived from the database at this point. *Only* when you actually try to access the results of the queryset (by e.g. iterating over the queryset, or by slicing it, or by accessing a single index in it), the queryset will build an (usually) *single* query that would retrieve only user records that satisfy *all* filtering conditions you have accumulated in your querysets up to that point. It will still need to filter your entire users table to find those matching users; it cannot take advantage of the "previously retrieved" users from the `group_of_users = Data.objects.filter(...)` queryset, because nothing has been actually retrieved at that point.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I feared. So is there no way to essentially minimize the size of the database I am looking at? I wanted to filter once to get a smaller set of data to filter against, but instead I am just filtering with redundant parameters. Is this just simply not how querysets work?

Comment: This is not how _databases_ work. If your first queryset _did_ pull the actual records from your database, then you wouldn't be able to apply any further filters to that set, because filtering happens in your database, not in a set of data _already retrieved_ into your application. You _could_ force retrieval with your first queryset (e.g. `group_of_users = list(Data.objects.filter(...))`), but then `group_of_users` would be a plain list of user instances and you wouldn't be able to use queryset filtering on it.

Comment: @lanzz It is possible, in theory, that django has methods that can filter through sets of data that have already been fetched by the db. I believe that is what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is exactly right and it is efficient.  The Querysets don't touch the database until they are evaluated, so you can add as many filters as you like and the database won't be touched.  [Django's excellent documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) provides all the information you need to figure out what operations cause the Queryset to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I feared. Is there any way to filter for a queryset, and then filter just that set of data? Or is this just not possible with querysets?